# Changing Colour of the Cell in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datagrid

i m having a problem in changing the color of cell in a datagrid in windows phone 7 application development,the problem precisely is when a new value is loaded in the cell it should check with the old value in cell and if the old value greater than new value it has to display a red color , if not it should display in blue color. In both the cases the new value will be Updated ,based on the previous value the color of cell should be updated. Pls Help me out.
I have tried in event currentvalue it hasnt worked. Is there any event which would help me get the old value and the current value of a cell in a datagrid?

Comment: What have you done till now? You'd need to show us some code

Comment: I don't remember seeing a built-in datagrid in Windows Phone. Can you indicate precisely which control you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got OnFormat or OnPostPaint events?  It's PostPaint for WinForms.

You'll need to keep a store of the old values though...i.e. you can't do it in the single event/step.

You capture the old value in one of the Finished Edit events, then compare them in the paint event.